# Any suggestions to answer this student visa question?

Tags: visas, usa

I am applying for an F-1 Student Visa for the USA. My major as an undergraduate was Electrical and Electronics but I am planning for Computer Science for my graduate degree.

How can I answer this question at a Visa interview?

**Why are you changing your stream?**

and

**What steps have you taken to ensure that you will be able to perform well in the new field you wish to change to?**

Comment: To be honest, I don't think you need a reason. "I thought I liked EE but it turns out, I like CS more."

Comment: what if the visa officer asks "Then why did you take Electricals in under grad?"

Comment: "As I said, I thought I liked EE but it turns out that what I liked about EE is present in CS more." TADAA!

Comment: Ok.. how is this?? 

Q) Why are you changing your stream? 
A) I thought I like EE but it turns out that I liked CS more. I realized it is the field I can put my heart in.

Comment: Check posted answer.

Comment: You've added another question to your post AFTER answers have provided. This is not a good idea on this site, and in addition, SE questions have one per post as a rule.

Comment: @user13807 I agree with Mark here as well.

Comment: oh... I didn't know that. I'll take care next time. Thankx..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be fairly honest, a question such as this is quite specific to a person or an individual. A Visa official is usually just trying to verify your *intent* but I understand you anxiety. So here's a sample answer I would have given.

Question - Why are you changing your stream?

Answer - Before I started with my undergraduate degree, I felt that I was interested in Electrical and Electronics Engineering. After spending some time in the stream and interacting with my fellow peers, I realized that I was better suited in the field of Computer Science. On consulting with my advisers at university, I decided that I could pursue my dreams by completing my Undergrad as an Electrical and Electronics student and then pursue my Graduate degree in the field of Computer Science.

The best answer to this question can be given by you yourself. And always remember that it's not as bad as it is portrayed to be many times.

Comment: Q) What steps have you taken to ensure that you will be able to perform well in the new field you wish to change to?

What will be good answer for this??

Comment: @user13807 Well, this one quite honestly is too specific. What *did* you do? Just say the truth and you'll be okay.

Comment: hmm..I understand.. how is my below response

A) I'm learning some programming languages and mastered Java programming. Also, I've registered for some free computer science courses online.

Comment: Nobody will believe you if you say you have "**mastered** Java".

Comment: You can never say that you have mastered something in IT. What you think you know now will be replaced with new tech tomorrow.